# Using MailApp to Send Email with Multiple Options

Tags: google-apps-script, html-email

I am trying to use Mail.App to send an email with an html body, and combining it with the option to change the "from" name and "replyTo" email address.

My current script is:

`MailApp.sendEmail (emailAddress, emailSubject, htmlBody, {htmlBody: htmlBody});`

I believe I should add {from: "name", replyTo: "replies@test.com"}. I end up with:

`MailApp.sendEmail (emailAddress, emailSubject, htmlBody, {htmlBody: htmlBody}, {from: "name", replyTo: "replies@test.com"});`

But it gave me an error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There should only be one `options` object in there, like this:

```
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, emailSubject, htmlBody,
    { htmlBody: htmlBody, name: 'Tuyen Nguyen', replyTo: 'replies@test.com' });
```

`MailApp` expects the third parameter in the first line there to be a plain text version of the email you are sending. In the event the recipient's email program does not support HTML email for some reason, it will show the plain text version instead.

You are using the `htmlBody` variable for both the plain text version and the HTML version of the email message. That technically works, but be aware that some recipients may see HTML tags in their email messages.

See [MailApp.sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)).

Comment: Thanks for this! The "replyTo" works, but the name doesn't show the way I want it to - it still just shows my name or my email address. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Use `name: 'somebody'` instead of `from: 'somebody'`. There is no `from` property in `MailApp.sendEmail()` options.

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Overflow. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
 MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "recipient@example.com",
    subject: "Logos",
    htmlBody: "inline Google Logo<img src='cid:googleLogo'> images! <br>" +
              "inline YouTube Logo <img src='cid:youtubeLogo'>});
 }
```

from this example: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object)

Check the link you can add any of the options into the object